# Python: How to calculate the cumulative of a row until each i?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe1 example:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  2  3  5  6
```

I have dataframe2 which is based on a cumulative and depends on dataframe1:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1
```

In order to calculate A2 in dataframe 2, i need to do df1.A2 * (1 - df2.A1). A3 in dataframe 2 is calculated as df1.A3 * (1 - df2.A1 - df2.A2) and so on.

Comment: This will give 0 as values of all columns after `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this like below:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1': [1],
    'A2': [2],
    'A3': [3],
    'A4': [5],
    'A5': [6]
})
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=dataframe1.columns)
for col in dataframe1.columns:
    if col == 'A1':
        dataframe2[col] = dataframe1[col]
    else:
        previous_cols = dataframe2.columns.tolist()[:dataframe2.columns.get_loc(col)]
        cum_sum = (dataframe1[col] * (1 - dataframe2[previous_cols].sum(axis=1))).cumsum()
        dataframe2[col] = cum_sum
print(dataframe2)
```

Output:

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
0   1   0   0   0   0
```